# restrict only space in textbox using html pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to not allow to user for enter only space character multiple times or single time in textbox using html pattern? Like see below example

1) {space character enter 1 or more times}ABCD -> Allow

2) AB{space character enter 1 or more times}CD -> Allow

3) ABCD1234 -> Allow

4) 1234@#!!!@@ABCD  -> Allow

5) ABCD{space character enter 1 or more times} -> Allow

6) {space character enter 1 or more times}   -> Not Allow

Only 6th number is not allow to enter user all other are allow Is there any expression for solve my above problem using html pattern attribute ?

Comment: you're looking for a regexp

Comment: `replace(/\s{2,}/, ' ')`

Comment: yes I am looking regexp and that reg i am use in pattern html 5 attribute

Answer (score 0):

This pattern might meet your requirements: `<input type="text" pattern="(\s*\S\s*)+" />`

Comment: if i add text only  :  abcde  then still it show me html 5 msg below 
Error: please match requested format.

Comment: Are you sure that you have no mistake in the pattern? Here's JSFiddle where it works with just text: https://jsfiddle.net/26trgqzt/

Comment: I have no mistake but I am use sonata admin of symfony framework

Comment: The backend framework shouldn't influence the way how browser determines whether input value matches provided pattern or not. At least, I don't know about such cases. Please, check if the middle `\S` is upper-cased. Also can you please specify the browser that you test it on?

Comment: I use chrome browser version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)